# Fixing CSS of profile page on my site (logged out view)

Tags: css

Please help me to fix the CSS error in profile on my site (IE).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the of profile http://j-in.org.ua:9000/account/profile/oleg

The username in red box is displayed on the middle of the page. and should be on the top of the page.

Comment: See screenshot: http://img.skitch.com/20090629-qn8uc7shpj544c8r4pm4qww2cs.jpg

Comment: Please don't repost your question again and again, this is the third time you ask exactly THE SAME QUESTION.

Comment: Sorry? Why do you say THE SAME? These are separate questions, which actually related to different blocks of code. Do you mean that, I should have post them not separately? or? Can you please explain!

Comment: This type of questions only helps the one asking the question, but is worthless for the community. How can I learn something here? Link to an external site: how long will it be available? Stackoverflow is not a bugtracker or your personal helpdesk. -1 and vote for close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `position: relative;` on `div#left` (or `#left` I haven't looked too closely at your CSS to see how you coded it), and `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` on the `p.head` element.

I'm not sure it'll work, but I'd rather offer you *some* help than see you post the same question yet again.

Let me know if that changes anything for the better -or worse- and hopefully we'll be able to build from there.